# What is the fastest way to split an array in r into a matrix of subsequences?

Tags: r, matrix, time-series

I am currently working on an anomaly detection algorithm in R which works on subsequences. Therefore I need to split a numeric array into a matrix which contains a row for each subsequence of the numeric array. Since the data can become very large, I am looking for the fastest way to do this.
So far my solution is:

```
split_into_subsequences = function(values, subsequence_count, subsequence_length) {
  subsequences <- matrix(0L, nrow=subsequence_count, ncol=subsequence_length)
  for(row in 1:nrow(subsequences)) {
    subsequences[row,] <- values[row:(row + subsequence_length - 1)]
  }
  return(subsequences)
}
```

Is there a faster way of doing this maybe by not using an explicit loop?

Comment: `embed(x, k)` from base R avoids looping.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that works and its also a lot faster even though i have to flip the matrix then afterwards as described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19820712/flip-the-matrix